# If $p\mid a^2$ then $p^2\mid a^2$. Show that it is true or false.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, square-numbers

For natural numbers $a$ and $p$ with $p$ prime, if $p$ divides $a^{2}$ then $p^{2}$ also divides $a^{2}$.

My understanding to the is if $p\mid a$, then $\gcd(a,p)$ should not be equal to $1$
 and so as $\gcd(a^2,p)$ and I do not know about $p^2\mid a^2$.

Please need clarification.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know the properties of a prime number?

Comment: canonical representation!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is it group theory?

Comment: @Nilan, I was just thinking the same.  It's number theory of course, but possibly the OP needs it for an application to group theory.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**.  A fundamental property of primes is: if $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ (or both).

What do you get if you apply this to the statement $p\mid a^2$?

Can you then finish the problem?

Comment: @Lynnie You are asked by David to *apply* the property to the statement. Not to repeat the statement :).

Comment: But $p\mid a^2$ is given, it doesn't help just to write it down twice ;-)  [Thanks @drhab for making that comment just as I was writing!]  Can you use the property I quoted in my first line to find some more specific information?

Comment: Well note if b|a and c|a then cb|a^2, im pretty sure

Comment: @user159813 That's also important.  Lynnie, can you now put all the pieces together?

Comment: Yes thanks ya'll it clear now.

Comment: The statement is true for all integers $a$.  This includes all natural numbers so the same proof works.  I guess your instructor or textbook is just not interested in the possibility of $a$ being negative.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, this is very simple. Write $$a=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{\alpha_i},$$ for primes $p_i$ and positive integers $\alpha_i$, so that $$a^2=\prod_{i=1}^np_i^{2\alpha_i}.$$ Since $p\mid a^2$, this implies that there exists $k$ with $p_k=p$. But then, $a^2$ has a factor of $p^{2\alpha_k}\geq p^2$, and we're done. $\blacksquare$